# Can not display data in primeng treetable, and Also response data returns undefined when console logged

Tags: angular

### Model

This is a model where I define what the data looks like

```
export interface NewEvaluation {

 id?: number;
 criteriaId?:number;
 parameterType?:string;
 parameterName?:string;
 weight?:number;
 thisYear?:number;
 lastMonth?:number;
 thisMonth?:number;
 comulative?:number;
 rate?:number;
 users?: string[];
 companyId?: number;
 criteriaName?: string;
 description?: string;
 ratingName?: string;
}

export class TreeNodeModel{
expanded: boolean;
data : NewEvaluation;
children:Array<TreeNodeModel>
}
```

### Import

importing the model in the service and component

import {TreeNodeModel} from '../../shared/model/newEvaluation';

### Component

this is how component looks like

```
newEvaluationInfo: TreeNodeModel[];
ngOnInit() {
   this.getAllEvaluations();}

this.projectDashboardService
  .getNewProjectEvaluationInfo(this.projectId).then((res:any) =>{
    this.newEvaluationInfo = res
    console.log(res, "tree data")
  });}
```

### Service

This is a method in the service to fetch the response from api

```
   getNewProjectEvaluationInfo(projectId:number){
     return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl2}/report/${projectId}/Project`, 
      this.tokenHelperService.getAuthToken())
       .toPromise()
     .then(res => <TreeNode[]> res);
    }
```

### Template

An html file to render the data

```
<p-treeTable [value]="newEvaluationInfo">
<ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>weight</th>
        <th>this_year</th>
        <th>last_month</th>
        <th>this_month</th>
        <th>comulative</th>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowNode let-rowData="rowData">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p-treeTableToggler [rowNode]="rowNode"></p-treeTableToggler>
            {{rowData.name}}
        </td>
        <td>{{rowData.weight}}</td>
        <td>{{rowData.this_year}}</td>
        <td>{{rowData.last_month}}</td>
        <td>{{rowData.this_month}}</td>
        <td>{{rowData.comulative}}</td>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

### Response data from api

```
[
{
    "Schedule": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "criteria_id": 1,
            "parameter_type": "Project",
            "name": "Schedule Performance based on Schedule variance (SV)",
            "weight": 20,
            "created_at": "2020-09-30 16:07:46",
            "updated_at": "2020-09-30 16:07:46",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "this_year": 0,
            "last_month": 0,
            "this_month": 0,
            "cummulative": 0
        }
    ]
},
{
    "Cost": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "criteria_id": 2,
            "parameter_type": "Project",
            "name": "Cost Performance based on Cost variance (CV)",
            "weight": 10,
            "created_at": "2020-09-30 16:07:46",
            "updated_at": "2020-09-30 16:07:46",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "this_year": 0,
            "last_month": 0,
            "this_month": 0,
            "cummulative": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "criteria_id": 2,
            "parameter_type": "Project",
            "name": "Cost Performance based on Cost Performance Index (CPI)",
            "weight": 10,
            "created_at": "2020-09-30 16:07:46",
            "updated_at": "2020-09-30 16:07:46",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "this_year": 0,
            "last_month": 0,
            "this_month": 0,
            "cummulative": 0
        }
    ]
},
{
    "Quality": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "criteria_id": 3,
            "parameter_type": "Project",
            "name": "Less frequent and acceptable defects are observed",
            "weight": 5,
            "created_at": "2020-09-30 16:07:46",
            "updated_at": "2020-09-30 16:07:46",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "this_year": 0,
            "last_month": 0,
            "this_month": 0,
            "cummulative": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "criteria_id": 3,
            "parameter_type": "Project",
            "name": "Reasonably less time taken to fix defects",
            "weight": 5,
            "created_at": "2020-09-30 16:07:46",
            "updated_at": "2020-09-30 16:07:46",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "this_year": 0,
            "last_month": 0,
            "this_month": 0,
            "cummulative": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "criteria_id": 3,
            "parameter_type": "Project",
            "name": "Tested samples pass specification requirements in the majority of the time",
            "weight": 5,
            "created_at": "2020-09-30 16:07:46",
            "updated_at": "2020-09-30 16:07:46",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "this_year": 0,
            "last_month": 0,
            "this_month": 0,
            "cummulative": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "criteria_id": 3,
            "parameter_type": "Project",
            "name": "Presence of quality control and quality assurance personnel, procedure and equipment in place",
            "weight": 5,
            "created_at": "2020-09-30 16:07:46",
            "updated_at": "2020-09-30 16:07:46",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "this_year": 0,
            "last_month": 0,
            "this_month": 0,
            "cummulative": 0
        }
    ]
},
{
    "Health and Safety": [
        {
            "id": 8,
            "criteria_id": 4,
            "parameter_type": "Project",
            "name": "Presence of health and safety personnel, procedure, and equipment in place",
            "weight": 5,
            "created_at": "2020-09-30 16:07:46",
            "updated_at": "2020-09-30 16:07:46",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "this_year": 0,
            "last_month": 0,
            "this_month": 0,
            "cummulative": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "criteria_id": 4,
            "parameter_type": "Project",
            "name": "Adequate and frequent health and safety meetings and related communications",
            "weight": 5,
            "created_at": "2020-09-30 16:07:46",
            "updated_at": "2020-09-30 16:07:46",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "this_year": 0,
            "last_month": 0,
            "this_month": 0,
            "cummulative": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "criteria_id": 4,
            "parameter_type": "Project",
            "name": "Occurrence of less severe and less frequent incidents/accidents",
            "weight": 5,
            "created_at": "2020-09-30 16:07:46",
            "updated_at": "2020-09-30 16:07:46",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "this_year": 0,
            "last_month": 0,
            "this_month": 0,
            "cummulative": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "criteria_id": 4,
            "parameter_type": "Project",
            "name": "Reasonably frequent health and safety meeting and related communications are conducted",
            "weight": 5,
            "created_at": "2020-09-30 16:07:46",
            "updated_at": "2020-09-30 16:07:46",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "this_year": 0,
            "last_month": 0,
            "this_month": 0,
            "cummulative": 0
        }
    ]
},
{
    "Environment": [
        {
            "id": 12,
            "criteria_id": 5,
            "parameter_type": "Project",
            "name": "Presence of environemntal protection policy and manual in place",
            "weight": 5,
            "created_at": "2020-09-30 16:07:46",
            "updated_at": "2020-09-30 16:07:46",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "this_year": 0,
            "last_month": 0,
            "this_month": 0,
            "cummulative": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 13,
            "criteria_id": 5,
            "parameter_type": "Project",
            "name": "Low air pollution and GHG emission",
            "weight": 5,
            "created_at": "2020-09-30 16:07:46",
            "updated_at": "2020-09-30 16:07:46",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "this_year": 0,
            "last_month": 0,
            "this_month": 0,
            "cummulative": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 14,
            "criteria_id": 5,
            "parameter_type": "Project",
            "name": "Low noise pollution",
            "weight": 5,
            "created_at": "2020-09-30 16:07:46",
            "updated_at": "2020-09-30 16:07:46",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "this_year": 0,
            "last_month": 0,
            "this_month": 0,
            "cummulative": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 15,
            "criteria_id": 5,
            "parameter_type": "Project",
            "name": "Low impact on vegetation, surrounding land escape, grounwater and the ecosystem",
            "weight": 5,
            "created_at": "2020-09-30 16:07:46",
            "updated_at": "2020-09-30 16:07:46",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "this_year": 0,
            "last_month": 0,
            "this_month": 0,
            "cummulative": 0
        }
    ]
},
{
    "Client Satisfaction": [
        {
            "id": 16,
            "criteria_id": 6,
            "parameter_type": "Project",
            "name": "Effective communication channel is in place",
            "weight": 5,
            "created_at": "2020-09-30 16:07:46",
            "updated_at": "2020-09-30 16:07:46",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "this_year": 0,
            "last_month": 0,
            "this_month": 0,
            "cummulative": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 17,
            "criteria_id": 6,
            "parameter_type": "Project",
            "name": "Less frequent claims and disputes",
            "weight": 5,
            "created_at": "2020-09-30 16:07:46",
            "updated_at": "2020-09-30 16:07:46",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "this_year": 0,
            "last_month": 0,
            "this_month": 0,
            "cummulative": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 18,
            "criteria_id": 6,
            "parameter_type": "Project",
            "name": "Clients requests and needs are attended fairly quickly and reasonably",
            "weight": 5,
            "created_at": "2020-09-30 16:07:46",
            "updated_at": "2020-09-30 16:07:46",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "this_year": 0,
            "last_month": 0,
            "this_month": 0,
            "cummulative": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 19,
            "criteria_id": 6,
            "parameter_type": "Project",
            "name": "Client's project objectives are well understood and addressed",
            "weight": 5,
            "created_at": "2020-09-30 16:07:46",
            "updated_at": "2020-09-30 16:07:46",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "this_year": 0,
            "last_month": 0,
            "this_month": 0,
            "cummulative": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I actually came back to answer my own question. It was easy, Either I had to map the response data to the one the tree node need or let the backend dev handle that. Becuase the TreeNode in primeng expects a data that has been structured accordingly...

This might some beginner devs struggling with the same questions....

Comment: Why didn't you explain what this TreeNode structure must be?!

Comment: I didn't add the treeNode structure because the data is already there on the documentation.

you can visit this link [Sample Tree Node Data](https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Ftree-table-dynamic-columns-demo.ts,src%2Fservice%2Fnodeservice.ts)